# BottomNavigationView from another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I have MainActivity which contains fragments (for example 3 fragments) and I can select fragment by BottomNavigationView.

Also i have button in OneFragment which start SecondActivity (which also contains BottomNagigationView).

[image]

**My question:**  When in SecondActivity i select bottomNV itemId two, I need to back to MainActivity with selected TwoFragment.

[image]

[image]

How can i realize it?

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BottomNavigationView navigationView;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationBottom);
    navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListelener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,
            new OneFragment()).commit();
}

public BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListelener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        setTitle(item.getTitle());
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.bottom_one:
                selectFragment(new OneFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.bottom_two:
                selectFragment(new TwoFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.bottom_three:
                selectFragment(new ThreeFragment());
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
};

private void selectFragment(Fragment selectedFragment){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_main, selectedFragment)
            .commit();
}

}
```

**SecondActivity.class**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BottomNavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seconda);

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationBottom);
    navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(1);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.bottom_one:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.bottom_two:
                //need to return to MainActivity with selected TwoFragment
                break;
            case R.id.bottom_three:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
}
```

Comment: So what you want If you go back to main activity you want to select first Tab right ?

Comment: @MD no, i need to select second Tab

Comment: Simple start activity by `startActivityAsResult (...)` from `fragment` and catch Action in main activity

Comment: @MD I tried, but doesn't work. My MainActicity has attribute launchmode  = singletask. Does it depend of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen in your code that the second activity is called SecondaActivity instead of SecondActivity. I supposed it is being misspelled and my code reflects the last one.

You can start the second activity using (someRequestCode is just a random int you can choose):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, someRequestCode);
```

Then in your second activity you can return OK in case 2 and KO in other cases (just for simplicity. If you want to elaborate a bit more you response, you can add some extra):

```
case R.id.bottom_two:
   //need to return to MainActivity which selected TwoFragment
   Intent data = new Intent();
   data.putExtra("key", "value"); // You can add data if needed. For example, number of fragment to be changed
   setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
   finish();
   break;
```

And finally in your MainActivity, override onActivityResult (someRequestCode is the same value as stated before):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == someRequestCode) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Here you can get key, value pair from extra and act accordingly
            selectFragment(new TwoFragment());
        } else {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. It is SecondActivity

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What is the thing that it is nor working? What does this code do to you?

Comment: It returns  a MainActicity fragmentOne

Comment: Try to remove the nested ifs in onActivityResult. Only the call to selectFrament and check if it works.

Comment: It works, if insert code in if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE)

Comment: Are you using the same code in startActivityForResult and onActivityResult?

Comment: Solved. Thanks. Simple, I forgot add getActivity() before startActivityForResult(intent, code);

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.bottom_two:
            //need to return to MainActivity which selected TwoFragment
   Intent intent = new Intent(SecondaActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
   intent.puExtra("fragment_no",2);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
   break;
```

In MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationBottom);
navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListelener);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras!=null)
{   intent number = extras.getInt("fragment_no");
if(number == 2)
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,
        new TwoFragment()).commit();
}
else
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,
        new OneFragment()).commit();
}
```

Comment: I think it should be better to finish second activity with a result and grab this result in MainActiviy. There is no need to start MainActivity again.

Comment: I thought that will be confusing for him

Comment: It may confuse him, I agree but in my opinion getting extras in onCreate may lead to confusion if he is not used to recreate activities, handle rotations and so on...

Comment: @MiguelIsla yes, activity is not recreated